# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to get value from the database, in my case I use `List` to get the value from the database but I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to id.co.bni.switcherservice.model.SwitcherServiceSource
at id.co.bni.switcherservice.controller.SwitcherServiceController.LoadData(SwitcherServiceController.java:48)
at id.co.bni.switcherservice.controller.SwitcherServiceController.main(SwitcherServiceController.java:62)
```

this is my code

```
    Query LoadSource = session_source.createQuery("select CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE,COUNT(*) FROM SwitcherServiceSource" +
            " where TIMESTAMP between :awal and :akhir" +
            " and PROVIDER_CODE is not null group by CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE order by CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE");
    LoadSource.setParameter("awal", fromDate);
    LoadSource.setParameter("akhir", toDate);

    List<SwitcherServiceSource> result_source = (List<SwitcherServiceSource>) LoadSource.list();
    for(SwitcherServiceSource tes : result_source){
        System.out.println(tes.getSERVICE());
    }
```

any help will be pleasure :)

@raffian, did you mean like this??

```
List<Switcher> result = (List<Switcher>) LoadSource.list();
for(Switcher tes : result){
    System.out.println(tes.getSERVICE());
}
```

Comment: @raffian That is a hibernate API method.

Comment: Does this problem happens for every select query ?
When some fields are retrieved from query out of all i absorb to follow the solution provided by Anikit Kulkarni.

When whole fields are retrieved from query this wont be a problem splatter_fadli

Comment: the answer Gleb S provided below is better than the accepted one, imo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486641/ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to#answer-40000155

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to id.co.bni.switcherservice.model.SwitcherServiceSource
```

Problem is

```
(List<SwitcherServiceSource>) LoadSource.list();
```

This will return a List of **Object arrays (Object[])** with scalar values for each column in the `SwitcherServiceSource` table. Hibernate will use ResultSetMetadata to deduce the actual order and types of the returned scalar values.

#### Solution

```
List<Object> result = (List<Object>) LoadSource.list(); 
Iterator itr = result.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
   Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
   //now you have one array of Object for each row
   String client = String.valueOf(obj[0]); // don't know the type of column CLIENT assuming String 
   Integer service = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(obj[1])); //SERVICE assumed as int
   //same way for all obj[2], obj[3], obj[4]
}
```

#### Related link

- [Using iterator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)

Answer (score 8):

I've faced such an issue and dig tones of material. So, to avoid ugly iteration you can simply tune your hql:

You need to frame your query like this

`select entity from Entity as entity where ...`

Also check such case, it perfectly works for me:

```
public List<User> findByRole(String role) {

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select user from User user join user.userRoles where role_name=:role_name");
    query.setString("role_name", role);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> users = (List<User>) query.list();
    return users;
}
```

So here we are extracting **object** from query, not a bunch of fields. Also it's looks much more pretty.

Comment: This saved my day! missing the "select x" in the hql was the key. I didn't need the casting (List<X>) though.

Comment: yup, I confirm the casting is not needed

Comment: `cannot find symbol`  -> `method addEntity`.

I am using the hibernate package. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add **query.addEntity(SwitcherServiceSource.class)** before calling the .list() on query.

Comment: Objects have been casted properly after adding entity in query. Thanks man!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me 

Answer (score 2):

Your query execution will return list of `Object[]`.

```
List result_source = LoadSource.list();
for(Object[] objA : result_source) {
    // read it all
}
```

Comment: I've try it and I got this error `cannot convert from element type Object to Object[]`

Comment: debug and find what is the element in list or you can do sout.

Comment: I think the problem is from this code `for(SwitcherServiceSource tes : result_source)`, I try to use "for each" to get value from database but failed... I think the element in list is Array ~

Answer (score 0):

In case entire entity is being return, better solution in spring JPA is use
@Query(value = "from entity where Id in :ids")

This return entity type rather than object type

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after a lot of research found this working solution.
For my HQL Query, I wanted to get the output of the **POJO** List, but I was getting a List of **Object**. **This is how you can get the list of your POJO class.**

Can achieve this in two ways:

> Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, **Picking**.class);
> **OR**
> Query query = em.createQuery(sqlQuery);

Working Example of **NativeQuery**:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

private <T> List getPickingQuery(Map<String, String> searchFields, Map<String, String> orderByFields,
                                                      Pageable pageable, String status) {
    List resultList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        String sql = "select * from picking where status = '" + status + "'";
        String sqlQuery = createQuery(sql, searchFields, orderByFields);
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, Picking.class);

        setQueryParam(sqlQuery, searchFields);
        query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
        query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
        log.info("Query " + query);
        resultList = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultList;
}

private String createQuery(String sql, Map<String, String> searchFields, Map<String, String> orderByFields) {
    for (String paramName : searchFields.keySet()) {
        sql = sql.concat(" and " + paramName + " = ?");
    }
    if (orderByFields != null) {
        if (orderByFields.containsKey("key") && orderByFields.containsKey("order"))
            sql = sql.concat(" order by " + orderByFields.get("key") + " " + orderByFields.get("order"));
        else if (orderByFields.containsKey("key"))
            sql = sql.concat(" order by " + orderByFields.get("key"));
    }
    return sql;
}

private void setQueryParam(String sqlQuery, Map<String, String> searchFields) {
    int param = 1;
    for (String paramName : searchFields.keySet()) {
        query.setParameter(param++, searchFields.get(paramName));
    }
}
```